# RegEx to find all indices for a unique character in 3 character sub-string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am getting indices of a pattern of two bytes using `finditer`.

```py
my_val = [0, 1]
[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(myval, content)]
```

But now I also need unique values/locations where the two first bytes are the same as `my_val`, but the 3rd value is unique. i.e in a pattern like: `013 234 523 015 68 012 9 015 014 012 013 013 012 012` I need `013`, `015`, `012`, and `014` neglecting duplicate values.

Comment: Your regex here is simply `(^| )01\d*`, where 0 and 1 are your values from `my_val`. Eliminating double values must be done in python (which I'm not used to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the pattern should be a bytes, note a list.

Then, You can use a dict to store the already found matches :

```
content = '0120150160150132468451018'
content = bytes(map(int, content))
my_val = b'\x00\x01.'
d = dict()
for m in re.finditer(my_val, content):
    k = m.group(0)
    if k not in d :
        d[m.group(0)] = (m.start(0), m.end(0))
res = d.values()
```

Note : to cast a `bytes` to a `list` of `int` and a `list` of `int` to a `bytes` :

```
>>> list(b'\x00\x03\xa2')
[0, 3, 162]

>>> bytes([0, 3, 162])
b'\x00\x03\xa2'
```

Comment: It all works fine until I have a string like this b'\x80\xf0\xffn(\xof'. But if it gets any '(' in the bytes it complains about "re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 2"

Comment: escape it, '(' is a regex metacharacter. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape

Comment: how to escape it? It is valid character made from  the value that I want to match against.